# TCP code in C gets stuck

Tags: c

This is the main part of my code after tcp connection establishment
When the username is correct, the program works perfectly, even if the password is not correct... but after a case of correct username, if I provide an incorrect username, the output will have no response ie termination is done by hard termination.

userlist.txt contains:
usernames passwords

CLIENT CODE

```
char user[256],pass[256],message[256];
char command[256],resp[256];
start:
printf("Enter username : ");
scanf("%s",user);
write(sockfd,user,strlen(user));
bzero(buffer,256);
read(sockfd,buffer,255);
//username is correct
if(strcmp(buffer,"username correct")==0)        
{
    printf("Enter password : ");
    scanf("%s",pass);
    write(sockfd,pass,strlen(pass));
    bzero(message,256);
    read(sockfd,message,255);
    printf("%s",message);
}
else
{
    printf("%s",buffer);        
}
goto start;
```

SERVER CODE

```
//username and password check
char user[256],pass[256],USER[256],PASS[256];
char command[256],names[256]="";
char temp[256];
int temps=0;
FILE *fp;
start:
fp=fopen("userlist.txt","r");
bzero(user,256);
read(newsockfd,user,255);
for(;fscanf(fp,"%s",USER)!=EOF;)
{
    if(strcmp(user,USER)==0)
    {
        write(newsockfd,"username correct",16);
        bzero(pass,256);
        read(newsockfd,pass,255);
        fscanf(fp,"%s",PASS);
        temps=1;
        if(strcmp(pass,PASS)==0)
            write(newsockfd,"success",7);
        else
            write(newsockfd,"invalid password ",17);
    }  
    else
    {
        fscanf(fp,user,PASS);
    }
}
if(temps==0)
{
    write(newsockfd,"invalid username ",17);
}
fclose(fp);
goto start;
```

Comment: `fopen` - Please check the return value. Ditto with `read` and the other calls. There is a reason for those return values

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: Why are you using `goto` as `while (true)` would be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are interleaving file access and network access. This is a bad idea.

What the code is doing is:

1. Read the name from the network:

   ```
   read(newsockfd,user,255);
   ```
2. Read the name from the file:

   ```
   fscanf(fp,"%s",USER)
   ```
3. Then compare.
4. Read the password from the network:

   ```
   read(newsockfd,pass,255);
   ```
5. Then read the password form the file:

   ```
   fscanf(fp,"%s",PASS);
   ```
6. Then compare.

At no point, you seek back to the start of the file. This means that you may end up attempting to read beyond the end of the file.

Instead of mixing these concerns (file access and network access), read name and and password and store them for future comparison when you need them.

---

In addition of that, the line:

```
fscanf(fp,user,PASS);
```

Is just wrong. The second parameter should be the `format` which the variable `user` does not represent.

---

I am aware I am not covering everything. We could, for example, talk about how to prevent buffer overflows, or even how to store passwords properly. I would surely miss a lot if I try (It has been a long time since I last used C anyway).

Still, I want to bring attention to the comments. In particular, if there one more thing you can take away with you is to check the return values of the functions.

Comment: 'read(newsockfd,pass,255);' does not have to load any bytes into the 'pass' buffer.  If it does, it may load [1,2,3......255] bytes.   If it does not happen to load the entire password, the check will fail.   Same with the earlier reading of 'user'.  Thsi is typical mishandling of TCP octet streams:(

Comment: Also it may not read in the null character to mark the end of a string . indeed it does not as `write(sockfd,user,strlen(user));` does not write that byte

Comment: @EdHeal yeah, but that's covered by the cargo-cult 'bzero' :(

Comment: @ZeeshanShamsuddeen I assure there are more bugs there

Comment: @Theraot yeah, lots:(

Comment: @ThingyWotsit - In part - assuming that it is under 255 bytes

Comment: yah i know.. I just started socket prgmng.. This is my frst project

Comment: @EdHeal the zero'd buffer is 256, so there will always be a NUL at the end, just as if the OP had done it properly and used a positive value returned by read().  TBH, all C-style NUL-terminated char array stuff is all bad in network code, as I'm sure you agree.